# How do I sum the records upto a limit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, sum

I have a table

```sql
CREATE TBALE #tableA  (PID int, Amount decimal (10,2), CorrectAmount decimal(10,2))

INSERT INTO #TableA (PID, Amount)
VALUES (1,100), (2,100), (3,100), (4,100), (5,100)
```

Logic to populate `correctAmount`:

1. Now I always need the sum of `CorrectAmount` as 350 (hard coded)
2. Keep the 'correct amount' as 'Amount' until its 350
3. Start with the top record until it hits 350.

Expected result:

`#tableA`:

```
PID  Amount CorrectAmount
-------------------------
1     100     100
2     100     100
3     100     100
4     100     50
5     100     0
```

Comment: What will be the value for records after 350?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? so basically I am doing is tally. 350 is constant. 350 - Amount = 100 (correct amount for 1) balance = 250, now 250 - amount = 100 for 2  and so on..

Comment: I mean what if there is another row with amount 100, what will be the value for CorrectAmount?

Comment: All the rows after it hits 350 (hard coded value) will be zero because there will be no balance.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I see that you deleted your previous solution. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: sorry. Can we edit it for 2008? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH Joined as(
    SELECT
        t1.PID,
        t1.Amount,
        RunningTotal = SUM(t2.Amount),
        PrevRunningTotal = SUM(t2.Amount) - t1.Amount,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(t2.Amount))
    FROM #tableA t1
    INNER JOIN #tableA t2 
        ON t2.PID <= t1.PID
    GROUP BY 
        t1.PID, t1.Amount
    HAVING 
        SUM(t2.Amount) > 350
)
UPDATE t
    SET t.CorrectAmount =
        CASE
            WHEN j.PID IS NULL THEN t.Amount
            ELSE
                CASE
                    WHEN j.rn = 1 THEN 350 - j.PrevRunningTotal
                    ELSE 0
                END
        END
FROM #tableA t
LEFT JOIN Joined j ON j.PID = t.PID
```